# I am stuck with a combinatoric problem...

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Well, I have to solve

$T_{n,k} =\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}{{n-k}\choose{i}}T_{n-1,k-1+i}$ where $T_{0,0}=1$, $T_{n,0}=0$ for $n>0$

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is $n \geq k$ ?.

Comment: What do you mean, "solve"? Do you need a non-recursive formula for $T_{n,k}$?

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes $n\geq k$

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Yup. I meant non-recursive formula for $T_{n,k}$

Comment: @FelixMarin: The equation implicitly says $T_{n,k}=0$ when $n<k$, as the sum is empty then.

Comment: What is $T_{n,k}$ supposed to be counting?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have no clue what $T_{n,k}$ represents

Comment: Then how is this a combinatorics problem? I guess you have to compute some two-parameter generating function?, so you're applying techniques that are also used in combinatorics..

Comment: Aren't these some Stirling numbers of some kind?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs 'Solve' means 'find a explicit or/and closed expression' for $T_{nk}$.

Comment: The sequence is http://oeis.org/A232006 with formula $T(n,k)=k*n^{n-k-1}$ given.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we have the recurrence

$$T_{n,k} = \sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n-k\choose q} T_{n-1, k-1+q}$$

where $T_{0,0} = 1$ and $T_{n,0} = 0$ for $n\gt 0.$

Put $S_{n, k} = T_{n, n-k}$ to obtain

$$S_{n,k} = \sum_{q=0}^{k} {k\choose q} S_{n-1, k-q}
= \sum_{q=0}^{k} {k\choose q} S_{n-1, q}.$$

where we now have $S_{n,n} = 0$ unless $n=0$ when we get the value $1.$

Following  the conjecture  $$S_{n, k}  = (n-k)  n^{k-1}$$ by  Marc Van
Leeuwen we prove  this by induction on $n$ with  base case $n=1.$ Note
that when $k=0$ the recurrence  unrolls to $S_{n,0}= S_{n-1,0} =\cdots
= S_{0,0} =1$  as pointed out in the comments.   This is indeed $(n-0)
n^{-1} = 1$ so we may assume that $k\ge 1$ in the induction.

We have for $n=1$ as the base  case that $S_{1,0} = 1$ which agrees as
just observed and $S_{1,1} = 0$ by definition which agrees as well.

For the induction step we need to evaluate

$$\sum_{q=0}^{k} {k\choose q} S_{n-1, q}
= \sum_{q=0}^{k} {k\choose q} (n-1-q) (n-1)^{q-1}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{k} {k\choose q}  (n-1)^{q}
- \sum_{q=0}^{k} {k\choose q} q (n-1)^{q-1}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{k} {k\choose q}  (n-1)^{q}
- k \sum_{q=1}^{k} {k-1\choose q-1} (n-1)^{q-1}
\\ = n^k - k \sum_{q=0}^{k-1} {k-1\choose q} (n-1)^{q}
= n^k - k n^{k-1} = (n-k) n^{k-1}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: +1. Fine work. I attempted to use a generating function but it became a cumbersome task. I left it !!!.

Comment: Nice job of turning powers of $n-1$ into powers of $n$. With the interpretation of $T_{n,k}$ as numbers of planted forests that I added to my answer, one can now ask if you have provided yet  another proof of their counting formula, essentially different from the two given by Stanley? In particular I'd like to think of a combinatorial interpretation of your manipulations.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer: experimental evidence suggests $T_{n,k}=kn^{n-k-1}$ (note that for $k=n$ this is $n/n=1$).

The next challenge is to understand where those powers of $n$ come from in the recurrence. This has the distinct smell of trees and forests.

So here is a combinatorial interpretation of $T_{n,k}$: it is the number of planted forests (disjoint union of trees, with a specified root node for each tree) on a labelled set of $n$ vertices, with a specified $k$-subset to be the set of roots. This interpretation is inspired by proposition 5.3.2 of R. P. Stanley's *Enumerative Combinatorics* (vol 2), which says that this number equals $kn^{n-k-1}$.

Here is why those combinatorial numbers satisfy the given recurrence. For $n=0$ one can of course only have the empty forest (with $k=0$), matching $T_{0,k}=\delta_{0,k}$. For $n>1$ we need at least one tree (so one root) whence $T_{n,0}=0$. Now assume the vertices are labelled by the set $[n]$ of the first $n$ natural numbers, and that the last $k>1$ of them are to be the roots (it clearly does not matter which $k$ labels are singled out to be the roots). For the final node, a root, choose a subset of the non-root nodes, which will be the set of its descendants. This subset has $i$ nodes with $0\leq i\leq n-k$. Now recursively choose a planted forest on the set $[n-1]$, with as root the remaining $k-1$ original root nodes together with the $i$ chosen (future) descendants. The number of possibilities is $\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}iT_{n-1,k-1+i}$, our given recurrence.

For a proof of the fact that now $T_{n,k}=kn^{n-k-1}$, I refer to the mentioned proposition; Stanley gives two proofs, one using Prüfer codes for planted forests and another using a bijection based on two views of permutations. Maybe I'll come back later to paraphrase either or both proofs.

Comment: With the recurrence we can show $T_{nn} = T_{n - 1,n- 1} = \cdots = T_{00} = 1$.

Comment: @FelixMarin That is obvious, but it barely scratches the surface. I suggested a formula valid for _every_ term with $k\leq n$. I just pointed out that it does give the expected result for $n=k$, though unexpectedly as a product involving a negative power of $n$.